# xampp не отображает страницу полностью

Tags: php, html, css, веб-программирование, xampp

Недавно я столкнулся с такой проблемой, с которой по-моему не сталкивался **ни один человек**. Дело в том, что когда я запускаю свою страницу php на localhost (xampp), отображается только шапка (половина). Фоновая картинка и всё.(И так кстати с любой страницей, не только *index.php*) Хотя у меня в коде есть тег main который занимает 120 строк в котором содержится различная информация. И почему-то  тег nav тоже отображается не полностью. **Занят этой проблемой уже 2 дня**. Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Вот весь код файла ***index.php***:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require 'db.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tk">
<head>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cormorant+SC:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amatic+SC&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="media/style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="serdar-a.png">
    <title>Lorem ipsum</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--Header-->
<?php
    include_once 'header.php';
?>
    <!--End of header-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="padding-top:10rem;text-align:center;font-family:Montserrat">
            <div class="col-12">
                <p class="hdr_image" >Lorem ipsum</p>
                <a href="#" type="button" class="btn btn-lg text-white get_start_btn">Lorem ipsum</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <main>
        <section class="spkr_wrld" style="font-family:Montserrat;">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6" style="margin-top:8rem;">
                        <div class="card text-white" style="background-color:#3762F0;box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 13px 27px -5px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 8px 16px -8px;">
                            <h5 class="card-header" >Lorem ipsum</h5>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title" >Lorem ipsum</h5>
                                <p class="card-text" >Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</p>
                                    <a href="chinese.php" type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Lorem ipsum</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6" style="margin-top:8rem;">
                        <div class="card text-white" style="background-color: #3762F0;box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 13px 27px -5px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 8px 16px -8px";>
                            <h5 class="card-header" >Lorem ipsum</h5>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title" >Lorem ipsum</h5>
                                <p class="card-text" >Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</p>
                                <a href="english.php" type="button" class="btn btn-dark" style="font-weight:500;">Iňlis dilini öwren</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    <div class="reg_div" >
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row" >
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 reg_form">
                    <h3 style="font-weight:400">Lorem ipsum</h3>
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputName1">Lorem ipsum:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Lorem ipsum">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group mt-3">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Lorem ipsum:</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Lorem ipsum">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group mt-3">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword2">Lorem ipsum:</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Lorem ipsum">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group mt-3">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">E-Poçta:</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Lorem ipsum">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-3" style="width:100%;">Lorem ipsum</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 reg_offer">
                    <h1 style="font-weight:800;text-align:center;" class="mt-3" >Lorem ipsum</h1>
                    <p class="p-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
                        et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
                        commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
                        pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="test">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <h1 class="header_of_page">Lorem ipsum:</h1>
          </div>
        <div class="row">
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-fluid overflow-hidden" style="margin-top:6rem;font-size:1.5rem;font-family:'Cormorant Garamond';">
        <div class="row gy-2 gx-8">
          <div class="col-12 col-lg-6" style="font-family:'Cormorant Garamond';">
            <div class="p-3 "><article class="quotes">"Lorem ipsum</article></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 mt-3">
            <div class="p-3 " style="text-align:right" ><article class="quotes">"Lorem ipsum</article></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 mt-3" style="padding-top:3rem;" >
            <div class="p-3 "><article class="quotes">"Lorem ipsum"</article></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    function generatePassword($length = 8){
        $chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstxvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890';
        $numChars = strlen($chars);
        $string = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $string .= substr($chars, rand(1, $numChars) - 1, 1);
        }
        return $string;
    }
    $password = generatePassword(8) . "n";
    echo $password;
?>
</main>
<?php
    include 'footer.php';
?>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.6.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-KsvD1yqQ1/1+IA7gi3P0tyJcT3vR+NdBTt13hSJ2lnve8agRGXTTyNaBYmCR/Nwi" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-nsg8ua9HAw1y0W1btsyWgBklPnCUAFLuTMS2G72MMONqmOymq585AcH49TLBQObG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Код файла ***header.php***:

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    $courses_sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM courses");
?>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light shadow bg-white rounded fixed-top" style="opacity:94%;">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><span class="brand_name" >Lorem ipsum</span></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.php">Главная</a>
            </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarScrollingDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                Курсы
                              </a>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarScrollingDropdown" style="box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 4px 12px;">
                                            <?php
                                            while ($courses_assoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($courses_sql))
                                            {
                                                ?>
                                            <li><a class="dropdown-item border_bottom" href="courses.php?id=<?php echo  $courses_assoc['id'];?>"><?php echo $courses_assoc['name']; ?></a></li>
                                            <?php
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </ul>
                     </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="contact.php">Обратная связь</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="about_us.php">О нас</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavDropdown">
<?php
            if ( isset ($_SESSION['logged_user']) )
                 {
                    echo '<ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <div class="btn-group dropstart">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary m-1 dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="28" height="28" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-person-circle" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                  <path d="M11 6a3 3 0 1 1-6 0 3 3 0 0 1 6 0z"></path>
                                  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 8a8 8 0 1 1 16 0A8 8 0 0 1 0 8zm8-7a7 7 0 0 0-5.468 11.37C3.242 11.226 4.805 10 8 10s4.757 1.225 5.468 2.37A7 7 0 0 0 8 1z"></path>
                                </svg>
                            </button>
                              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                                <article class="dropdown-item">';echo $_SESSION['login'];  echo'</article>
                                <hr style="margin:0;padding:0;">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="change_login.php">Сменить логин</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="change_email.php">Сменить Email</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="change_pw.php">Сменить пароль</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="logout.php">Выйти</a>
                              </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>';
                 }
                 else {
                    echo '<ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                          <button class="btn btn-outline-dark login-btn" href="sign_in.php" type="button">Войти</button>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                          <button class="btn reg_button_hdr" style="background-color:#D7E0FC;color:#4A71F1;" href="register.php" type="button">Регистрация</button>
                        </li>
                      </ul>';
                 }
?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <style>

    </style>
```

Comment: А если закомментировать шапку, что-то изменится?

Comment: А если открыть исходный код html-страницы то что там видно? А отображение ошибок ежли еще включить?

Comment: @u_mulder, Если открыть код также видно код полу-шапки и тег <main> полностью отсутствует.

Comment: @OliverPatterson, Я попробовал ещё раз и всё получилось. Но как мне быть без шапки?

Comment: полные пути к файлам используй

Comment: Возможно что в шапке ошибка в пхп коде. Хотя вроде инклуды выбрасывают лишь варнинг, а не еррор.. или это относится к файлам, кхм) Приложи код хеадера.

Comment: @OliverPatterson, извивните, я захожу с телефона, код не могу приложить, но я попробовал перенести `include 'header.php';` после тега main. И всё сработало. Но почему-то отображается половина шапки. Что за странная ошибка?

Comment: А шапка всегда одинаково не прогружена? То есть.. если в разных местах инклуд. Если да, то скорее тут без кода не поймешь в чем проблема. Может синтаксическая ошибка в html разметке.

Comment: @OliverPatterson,извините, что долго. Я выложил код шапки

Comment: Еще раз) А шапка всегда одинаково не прогружена? Какая часть из этого файлла загружена, а какая нет? Можете дать такую информацию?

Comment: @OliverPatterson, наконец-то я нашёл виновника, оказывается в коде шапки имеется Фатальная ошибка. Стало понятно почему когда я переношу шапку вверх, main не отображается. А видно ошибку не было потому-что она находилась в Dropdown. А последняя не открывалась. Большое спасибо, за помощь!

Comment: Когда-то я отключил отображение ошибок и вывод их в файл, потом понял, что хотя бы в файл их нужно выводить)

Comment: @OliverPatterson, извините, я наверное уже вам надоел, но не сможете помочь с ошибкой. Она ругается на строку: `while ($courses_assoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($courses_sql))` (**header.php**). Ошибка : `Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_fetch_assoc(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool given in ...` .

Comment: `fetch_assoc` принимает только `array|null|false`. Подробнее: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Хотя опять же нужно немного больше кода, который был перед) А вижу.. Кхм

Comment: Нужно смотреть что возвращает `$courses_sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM courses");`.

Comment: @OliverPatterson, я использовал `var_dump($course_sql)`, и увидел что оно возвращает следующее: `bool(false)`.

Comment: А таблица `courses` пустая? Может вы не так написали название ее в запросе? Как минимум перед `mysqli_fetch_assoc` нужно проверять значение `courses_sql` на `false`.

Comment: @OliverPatterson, нет в таблице `courses` содержится строка (одна). И нет, вроде всё правильно, таблица `courses`, и запрос `"SELECT * FROM courses"`

Comment: Попробуйте название таблицы взять в апострофы (\`)

Comment: @OliverPatterson,  к сожалению ничего не изменилось)

Comment: Может можем где-то связаться, чтобы тут не плодить комментарии и выложить в чем была проблема? Например телеграм?

Comment: Кхм.. А вы не забыли указать название базы данных в `mysqli_connect`?)

Comment: @OliverPatterson, Дааа! Наконец-то, спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: Не забудьте так же указать базу данных перед функцией генерациии пароля. А так же почитайте вот по этой ссылочке https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php думаю будет полезно)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в попытке вызова функции `mysqli_fetch_assoc` с булевым параметром, т.к. при `mysqli_connect` не было указано название базы данных, `mysqli_query` возвращал `false`, что в итоге возвращало фатальную ошибку.